Numerically zero line bundles
I have a very basic question -- I must be doing something wrong. Here is the setup of my question. Let $S$ be a nonsingular projective surface over an algebraically closed field. We have an intersection pairing on $Pic(S)$ given by
$$
(L_1.L_2) = \chi(\mathcal{O}_S) - \chi(L_1^{-1}) - \chi(L_2^{-1}) + \chi(L_1^{-1} \otimes L_2^{-1}). 
$$
A useful lemma is that if $C$ is an effective divisor, and $H$ is very ample, then $(C.H) > 0$. This can be found, for example, on page 10 of Lectures on K3 surfaces by Daniel Huybrechts.
Now here is my question. Many authors define $Pic^\tau(S)$ to be the subgroup of $Pic(S)$ of numerically zero line bundles, i.e. line bundles $L$ such that $(L.L') = 0$ for all $L' \in Pic(S)$.
My question is: how can this be nonempty? For example, let us suppose we had some $D \in Pic^\tau(S)$. Let $H$ be a very ample divisor. By Serre's theorem, we know that for large enough $n$, $nD$ admits a section. Then $nD$ will be linearly equivalent to some effective divisor $C$. Then
$$
(nD.H) = (C.H) > 0 \implies n(D.H) > 0 \implies (D.H) > 0.
$$
Then it seems there are no numerically zero line bundles.. but surely I have made a mistake somewhere. Could someone help me? Thanks a ton!

By Serre’s theorem, D + nH will admit sections for large n. Not nD.

Ah! What a stupid mistake. How embarrassing. I tricked myself from my own writing. Thank you!

It's not true that $nD$ admits a section for any $n >> 0$. Consider, for example, an elliptic curve $(E, O)$, a non-torsion point $P$, and the divisor $D = P - O$. Then $nD$ will not admit global sections for $n > 0$.
